# How can I edit, add and delete transient entities from a Set?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have what I feel must be a common problem: I have a `Communication` object that describes ways to communicate with a `Person`. Naturally, I display instances of a person's `Set<Communication>` in a datatable. I want the end user to be able to dynamically add and delete rows from this table.

Both objects usually use `equals()` and `hashCode()` based on their database PK. The PK is generated by a postgresql sequence (the column is of type `serial`). This is not sufficient here since I can only add one (transient) element with a `null` PK.

The only option offered by the [hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes-equalshashcode) is to implement equals and hashCode in terms of business equivalence. Since the Communication object is basically a glorified `String`, this is not possible. A user needs to edit every aspect of the object.

I've thought about creating a sequence service that "reserves" a id for the transient entity and assigns it to the object on creation. But I fear this interferes with Hibernate's ability to determine if the entity is transient or not.

So the question is: are there better options to edit, add and delete transient objects when I can't provide business key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about hibernate for a moment. You are talking about adding elements to a set and they have no identity at all since all attributes may be modified and they have no identifier. That is wrong. Sets are for identifiable elements. Use a list or make elements identifiable. You can assign them a temporal ID or a real database ID or whatever but the problem is not with Hibernate, it is about the concept of Set.

Comment: That's why I said one solution is fetching a sequence value ahead of their eventual persistence and assigning it to the object. I'd go ahead with it *if Hibernate lets me*. But yeah, you're probably right about a `List` with `@OrderColumn` being the better choice here.